# how to get response message when user enters the text using flask?

Tags: python, html, flask, chatbot

I created a chatbot using for loop.In browser it is not giving response when user enters the text.

I tried like below:

app.py:

```
import flask
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from werkzeug.wrappers import Request, Response
import pandas as pd
import re
#####***** Reading the data
data=pd.read_excel("path",sheet_name='Sheet2')
#######**** Converting columns to a lists
userList=data["User"].tolist()
cbList=data["CB"].tolist()
app = Flask(__name__)
##########***** asking user to enter their questions and giving responses 
bot_response=[]
for i in range(0,len(userList)):
        user=input("User:")
        if user=='':
            print("Bye")
            break
        userReg=re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]'," ",user.lower())
        userRegSplit=(userReg.split())
        ud=str(userList[i]).lower()
        ud=re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]'," ",ud)
        newList=ud.split()
        commonWords=[x for x in newList if x in userRegSplit]
        if len(commonWords)==len(newList):
            bot_response.append(cbList[i])
            print(bot_response)
@app.route('/')
def CBApp():
    return render_template('CBApp.html')
@app.route("/get")
def get_bot_response():
    userText = request.args.get('msg')
    return str(bot_response.get_response(userText))
if __name__=='__main__':
    from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
    app.debug=True
    run_simple('localhost',port,app)
```

html template will look like below:

```
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rY4tW.png
```

suggest me where am gone wrong?

Comment: Can you share any error messages that might show what's going on? What does your html template look like?

Comment: @Till, When i ran the app getting html template look above but when enter **Hi** message we should get automatic response from bot.For getting response from bot the logic is  for loop.Now i am getting ```Attribute error: list object does not  have get_response.

Comment: This isn't really how flask should be used.  You're prompting for user input with the `input` function that runs at the console, but ultimately want the user to interact with the app through the browser.  If this was deployed properly end-users would not have access to the console at-all.  You may wish to start with [this tutorial](https://codeburst.io/building-your-first-chat-application-using-flask-in-7-minutes-f98de4adfa5d) which explains implementing a chat room app with flask using sockets.io.  This is probably a good base on-top of which you could build some bot logic.

Comment: @v25,I was stuck there, I used website guided by you but no use.

Comment: @Magie I've put this together in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/vulcan25/0c0a99a85f9528e1d66361d95ae0665f) with a few updates from the original tutorial if that helps, along with a README.